# A question on matrices whose minimal polynomials has no repeated roots

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, minimal-polynomials

**Question**

a) Prove that a matrix $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ satisfying $A^3=A$ can be diagonalized.

b) Does the statment in (a) remain true if one replaces $\mathbb{C}$ by an arbitrary algebraically closed field $F$?

**Answer**

First of all, we can see that the matrix $A$ satisfies the polynomial $p(X)=X(X-1)(X+1)$. Since the minimal polynomial has to divide $p(X)$, we can conclude that the minimal polynomial of $A$ has no repeated root. This would yield that $A$ can be diagonalized. However, I couldn't answer the part (b). Actually, I do not know what the crucial part $\mathbb{C}$ plays in part (a) either. Thanks a lot in advance...

Comment: Potentially related: $p$ has a repeated root in any field of characteristic $2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no; the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
with entries in the algebraic closure of $\mathbb F_2$ (for example) is not diagonalizable but satisfies $A^3=A$. Its characteristic and minimal polynomial is $(x-1)^2$ which is equivalent to $x^2-1$ in characteristic $2$.

“Algebraically closed” in this case is a bit of a red herring; the fact that $\mathbb C$ has characteristic zero, hence $x^3-x$ truly splits into linear factors, is the reason why it works over $\mathbb C$. In the case above, $$x^3-x = x(x^2-1) = x(x-1)^2$$
so your minimal polynomial might not split into distinct linear factors.

Comment: I see! Then we also require the field being characteristic $0$. So, can we say that this also holds true for $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ ?

Comment: Since $(x-1)^2 = x^2-2x+1$, the condition we need to avoid is $2=0$, so we require the field to not have characteristic two. Yes, it also works in $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ for the same reason.